# I want to make a file browser app for iPhone, but I don't know where to start

Tags: iphone, objective-c, filesystems, jailbreak, cydia

I want to make a simple file browser app for iPhone. (Like iFile in Cydia)
It's not a just view Documents folder, it can see **all directories** in the iPhone/iPod Touch File System.
Like a Finder on Mac/Explorer on the Windows.

Who can help me?

P.S. I'll publish to Cydia Store, not App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need the iPhone SDK up and running and you're going to want to go over the [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this if you want to publish to the app store. You are not allowed to access files outside of your own sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps operate in their own little sandboxes -- they can't see into other apps' directories. So unless you're writing an app for a jailbroken device, you're out of luck.